# uncaught runtime error error could not start video source - React.js using getUserMedia

Tags: reactjs, getusermedia

```
    import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { IoClose } from "react-icons/io5";

export default function CapturePhoto({ hide, setImage }) {
  const videoRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let stream;
    const startCamera = async () => {
      stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: true,
        audio: false,
      });
      videoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
    };
    startCamera();
    return () => {
      stream?.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
    };
  }, []);
  const capturePhoto = () => {
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(videoRef.current, 0, 0, 300, 150);
    setImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"));
    hide(false);
  };
  return (
    <div className=" absolute h-4/6 w-2/4 top-1/4 left-1/3 bg-gray-900 gap-3 rounded-lg pt-2 flex items-center justify-center">
      <div className=" flex flex-col gap-4 w-full ">
        <div
          className="pt-2 pr-2 cursor-pointer flex items-end justify-end"
          onClick={() => hide(false)}
        >
          <IoClose className="h-10 w-10 cursor-pointer" />
        </div>
        <div className="flex justify-center ">
          <video id="video" width="400" autoPlay ref={videoRef}></video>
        </div>
        <button
          className="h-16 w-16 bg-white rounded-full cursor-pointer border-8 border-teal-light p-2 mb-10"
          onClick={capturePhoto}
        ></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When ever I run this code It gives me uncaught error: error could not start video source.
In the console it gives uncaught(in promise): DOMException: Could not start video.
Can anyone please help me to solve this problem for this I am not able to complete my project.
I am using react.js for this project.

Comment: I have also given permission to capture video from my device i.e from window and web browser.

Comment: Your `startCamera()` method is async. That means when you call it (as you do) from a non-async method it returns a Promise. You should either call it from an async method with `await startCamera()`, or pass its result to `.then()`.

Comment: not able to get. please can you provide me the code..

Comment: I have use in the above code please see the above code..but now it is working sometime and sometimes giving the same error...